# Golang []byte в качестве ключа map[[256]byte] *Block

Tags: golang, blockchain

Хочу, чтобы можно было искать блоки по их полю хэша. Код такой:

```
package main

type Blockchain struct {
    blocks []*Block
    table  map[[256]byte] *Block
}

func (bc *Blockchain) AddBlock(data string) {
    prevBlock := bc.blocks[len(bc.blocks) - 1]
    newBlock := NewBlock(data, prevBlock.Hash)
    bc.blocks = append(bc.blocks, newBlock)
    bc.table[newBlock.Hash] = newBlock;
}
```

Где блок объявлен так:

```
type Block struct {
    Timestamp     int64
    Data          []byte
    PrevBlockHash []byte
    Hash          []byte
}
```

В поле Hash содержится SHA256 блока.

При компиляции получаю несоответствие типов данных:

> cannot use ([]byte)(newBlock.Hash) (type []byte) as type [256]byte in
>   map index

Что мне можно сделать с типами данных, чтобы этот код работал? Язык Go, изучаю его первый день.

Answer (score 1):

Слайсы не являются сравниваемыми и не могут использоваться в качестве ключа map. Конвертируйте срез в массив:

```
var sha256 [32]byte // sha256 занимает 32 байта (256 бит)
copy(sha256[:], newBlock.Hash)
bc.table[sha256] = newBlock
```

Вместо среза для фиксированного хеша лучше использовать массив. Проблем будет меньше.